# C++11: Compile and Execute: cross-platform compilation

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, cross-platform

I have a short C++ code that I have successfully compiled on a remote server `A`. I wish to run the executable on another target remote server `T`.

The code `main.cpp` contains the following snippet (requires C++11 support):

```
#include <random>
default_random_engine GENERATOR;
void get_random_indices(set<int> &output, int max_ind) {
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, max_ind);
    
    while (output.size() < SAMPLE_SIZE) {
        output.insert(dist(GENERATOR));
    }
}
```

I compiled the code using the following line:

```
g++ -o exec_foo -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

The spec of server `A` is

```
[me@A ~]$ uname -a
Linux some-ip:D 2.6.32-573.1.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 14 02:46:51 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[me@A ~]$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/nfs/nfs5-insecure/home/insecure-ro/software/rhel6_x86_64/gcc-5.1.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ./configure --prefix=/l/gcc-5.1.0
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.1.0 (GCC)
```

When I run the `exec_foo` in server `A`, it works fine. Now running the same executable on the target server `T` results in the following error:

```
./exec_foo: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by ./exec_foo)
./exec_foo: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by ./exec_foo)
./exec_foo: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./exec_foo)
```

Checking the spec on target server `T`, I see the following:

```
-bash-4.1$ uname -a
Linux marry-christmas 2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.marry-christmas.20130516.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 17 04:49:39 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

-bash-4.1$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)
```

OK, I get it. Server `T` can't find some links of library. But I can't compile the code natively on `T`:

```
-bash-4.1$ g++ -o exec_foo --std=c++11 main.cpp 
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

No `c++11`. Let's try `c++0x`.

```
-bash-4.1$ g++ -o exec_foo --std=c++0x main.cpp 
main.cpp:64: error: ‘default_random_engine’ does not name a type
main.cpp: In function ‘void get_random_indices(std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >&, int)’:
main.cpp:66: error: ‘uniform_int_distribution’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:66: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
main.cpp:66: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’
main.cpp:69: error: ‘GENERATOR’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:69: error: ‘dist’ was not declared in this scope
```

Besides updating the bloody `g++` + `gcc` on server `T`, which I don't have rights to do, is there a way out?

Comment: Try building with `-static-libstdc++`. Also, check the glibc version - if the version on server `T` is older you may try going down to `-static` (as long as you don't use sockets - IIRC there was some problem when doing a fully static link when using threads). But in general, on Linux the binary compatibility situation is extremely sad, the only way I found to reliably port an executable across different versions is to build on an older Linux linking statically as much stuff as possible *excluding glibc*.

Comment: @MatteoItalia It worked! You should put it as an answer. Maybe put up a link to the doc. I will accept it.